# Importing urllib2 in python

Tags: urllib2, importerror

For some reason, importing urllib2 in python gives me an importerror. I can import urllib successfully...what is going on?

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
ImportError: No module named urllib2
```

Answer (score 1):

what version of python are you using? in python 3 the name has changed (from the manual):

> Note The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in
>   Python 3.0 named urllib.request and urllib.error.